# Possible to switch from @proton.me to @protonmail.com?

Tags: protonmail

I went to `protonmail.com` to sign my child up for an account. I didn't notice that there was an option between `proton.me` and `protonmail.com` and that it defaulted to `proton.me`.

I then signed my child up for an advantage account on `aa.com` using `@protonmail.com`. I know I can call American Airlines and get them to change the email, but my other children have `@protonmail.com` accounts and I'd like to keep it consistent if possible.

I did try to go back and sign up for an account selecting `@protonmail.com`, however it said the username was already taken. But when I try to do a reset password for that account it says the account doesn't exist and a test message I sent to the account got bounced back, so I believe it is just not letting me create the `@protonmail.com` account because the username is already being used for `@proton.me`.

So is it possible to change my child's `@proton.me` account to be `@protonmail.com`?

Comment: Protonmail is a web application. It is more appropriate here. My initial comment was made on Super User. It made no sense here. Thus site (Web Applications) is better for a question like this. You should still attempt to contact Protonmail support to clear this up.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Ah gotcha, I didn't realize this was a site to help end users with navigating public web applications, but thought it was another developer site. The protonmail label should probably be removed from SuperUser then I suspect because it's a little strange to have a label for something that's off topic. (I suppose it's left over from before this site was available)

Comment: I previously suggested you contact ProtonMail support directly and I still recommend that: https://proton.me/support/mail